# Unable to publish ASP.NET Core application with "CreateManifestFile" task could not be loaded

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, microsoft-web-deploy

I have an ASP.NET Core app which I can publish using web deploy and pre-configured publishing profile via Visual Studio 2017. Now I need to configure CI and trying to achieve the same from the command line so I installed `[.NET Core SDK][1]` and followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/web-publishing-vs?tabs=aspnet1x)

```
dotnet build -c release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=publish-profile-name
```

Unfortunately, it gives the following error:

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstanda
>   rd1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(227,5):
>   error MSB4062: The "CreateManifestFile" task could not be loaded from
>   the assembly C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0
>   ....\tools\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.NETCore.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.dll. 
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

How can I fix the `dotnet build` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your publish profile uses MSDeploy, it cannot be built via the .NET Core based build tools (`dotnet build`).

See the related GitHub issue https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/166

The workaround is to use `msbuild /p:Configuration=Release …` from a VS 2017 installation instead of `dotnet build`.

Comment: I saw this discussion but also notice this: `We have also fixed the task to run on core. So, you should be able to run the below command once the new websdk is released.` so I assumed that it's already fixed. Is it an issue for the web deploy only? I can totally switch my publishing profile to FTP...

Comment: I think the comment was about `WebDeployPackage` and not `MSDeploy`. AFAIK the package should allow you to deploy the resulting zip file using `msdeploy.exe` or the IIS GUI.

Comment: I've created an FTP deploy and was able to pass this step without errors, but, unfortunately, new files are not being copied to ftp server with Build Succeeded output. The command is below: `dotnet build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=myprofile-ftp`

Comment: I suggest opening an issue on the linked websdk repo about that